# Problem with translating characters with tr (POSIX) in GAMS

Tags: csv, posix, gams-math

In GAMS version 33.2.0, I am changing the semi-colons to commas in a csv-file 'file.csv' because GAMS demands commas as separators. Then I want to transfer the content of the csv-file into a table in GAMS and then save it in a gdx-file. When I run the code below, the semi-colons are succesfully replaced by commas but despite this, GAMS cannot make a table of it. I get error 326: an empty table statement is not followed by a legal statement and the error occurs when the first comma is encountered in the csv-file 'file_temp.csv'. Why does GAMS not recognize the comma as separator?

The file 'file.csv' contains:

```
;col1;col2;col3
row1;1;2;3
row5;4;5;6
row3;7;8;9
row4;10;11;12
```

My code is:

```
Sets
    column /col1, col2, col3/
    row /row1, row2, row3/;
$onempty
$call "tr ; , <file.csv > file_temp.csv"
Table tab(row,column)
$ondelim
$include file_temp.csv
$offdelim
;
$offempty
execute_unload 'tab.gdx'
```

Comment: Just guessing, but for a shell executing that call, `tr ; ,` is the same as the command `tr` followed by the command `,` because the `;` is a command separator.  Try `tr \; , <file.csv > file_temp.csv` or `tr ';' , <file.csv > file_temp.csv` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @MemReflect Thanks for your comment! I tried it now but it did not work. As I wrote, the file 'file_temp.csv' has commas instead of semicolons as separators, so the translation seems to work but GAMS does not understand the commas as separators although it should...

Comment: Since I've never used GAMS, my only other idea is your lack of `row4` and `row5` in your Set (or missing `row2` in your CSV file) might be a problem. Perhaps someone who is familiar with the software can help more.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your model, I get a domain violation error. The problem is, that you defined `row` as `row1, row2, row3` while you have `row5` in your data. After extending the `row` set, things worked for me:

```
$onEcho > file.csv
;col1;col2;col3
row1;1;2;3
row5;4;5;6
row3;7;8;9
row4;10;11;12
$offEcho

Sets
    column /col1, col2, col3/
    row /row1 * row5/;
$onempty
$call "tr ; , <file.csv > file_temp.csv"
Table tab(row,column)
$ondelim
$include file_temp.csv
$offdelim
;
$offempty
execute_unload 'tab.gdx';
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have read through my code before posting here. My idea was just to have row1, row2, row3, row4 but then of course I should have assigned the set row as /row1, row2, row3 row4/. This was however not the reason for the "an empty table statement is not followed by a legal statement"-error but I found out what was wrong. I wanted to be able to transfer data from Excel to GAMS so, what I should have mentioned, is that I created file.csv in Excel. The mistake was that I saved it in the format CSV UTF-8 which seems to have confused GAMS. When I saved as a CSV-file it worked!